# Incorrect timestamp in c# multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, logging, timestamp

I'm write my own logger in c#. When i'm using this logger in multithreads i hit to some problem with time. It seams that each thread has different time. Method which logs info is locked for only one thread and in file messages are in correct order but some timestamps shows that some messages should be before some messages, but for 100% i'm sure that order is correct, timestamp is not.
This is method:

```
private void WriteToFile(string message, string label)
{
    lock (this.semaphore)
    {
        var msgLines = message.Split('\n');
        var timeStamp = string.Format("[{0}]", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy:MM:dd:HH:mm:ffff"));
        foreach (var line in msgLines)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
            {
                continue;
            }

            var msg = string.Concat(timeStamp, this.groupIndicator, label, line).Trim();
            this.writer.WriteLine(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Where type of semaphote is object and writer is StreamWriter
And there is output:

```
[2016:11:15:13:06:2896]---> [MESSAGE] Test message <- one thread    
[2016:11:15:13:06:2973]---> [MESSAGE] Test message <- one thread    
[2016:11:15:13:06:3033]---> [MESSAGE] Test message <- one thread
[2016:11:15:13:06:1956]---> [MESSAGE] Different message  <- different thread
```

And I 100% sure that messages are in correct order, but something strange is happening with time.
Strange thing is happening when I add timestamp before method WriteToFile. Time was exactly this same!

```
[2016:11:15:15:41:8828]---> [MESSAGE] time: 2016:11:15:15:41:8828, Test message <- one thread 
[2016:11:15:15:41:9064]---> [MESSAGE] time: 2016:11:15:15:41:9064, Test message <- one thread
[2016:11:15:15:41:2515]---> [MESSAGE] time: 2016:11:15:15:41:2515, Different message  <- different thread
```

I was searching for other methods to get current time, but according also to stack overflow DateTime.Now should be correct.

Comment: Cant get what's wrong in here. Your `different message` is done before the others. Cant say anything to the `why` because I cant see how these threads are triggered.

Comment: Try to flush stream before exit lock.

Comment: Look for time. Oldest message is on the top (like in console) according to time last message should be first one but this is physically impossible. Threads are triggered like this: thread one execute some command and second thread  is waiting for specific output, when find's this output thread writes this message to logger.

Comment: I see the problem is that the timestamp ordering the last one gives the least timestamp value

Comment: It would help if you could edit your question to include the actual multithreaded usage.

Comment: What makes you think that a thread that is about to write to Console.WriteLine() can't get pre-empted by another thread, which writes its own message first?

Comment: Remember to use the same instance of your class since `semaphore` isn't static field.

Comment: Matthew Watson, second thread is waiting for some output from thread one. Thread one is writer, thread two is reader. Messages are in correct order, this "different message" couldn't occurs before other because second thread waits for first one.

Comment: @mefmund I'll believe that when you post the actual code... ;)

Comment: Sorry but i cannot, company policy. :( I can writes how it works thread one registy some keywords to be founded in output, f.e. "error", and sending through ssh command, let say 'ls', when data come back second thread search for registered keyword, if find fire some action, which among others is log that keyword was founded.

Comment: @mefmund You should at least be able to write a repro? If you can't, then there's little point in posting the question here since without code nobody can really help you.

Comment: @Matthew Watson what more info you need? I tryed to explain in my last comment how it works. :)

Comment: @mefmund I believe that there is a problem with your code, but because I cannot see your code I cannot diagnose it. Just vaguely describing code isn't going to help. You ideally need to write a compilable console app that reproduces the issue, otherwise it's pretty much impossible to help you.

Comment: There is only 1 clock.

Comment: "messages are in correct order" - there is no such thing as 'correct' here. You have to impose the order. Post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Answer for this question is very easy. : >
Problem is here: DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy:MM:dd:HH:mm:ffff")), there is no seconds in this format. What i took for a second it was in fact minutes.